# How to initialize an array in Kotlin with values?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

In Java an array can be initialized such as:

```
int numbers[] = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
```

How does Kotlin's array initialization look like?

Comment: Maybe just have a look at the docs: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Comment: The documentation somewhat hides the answer. Instead of giving a source code example they mention the (deprecated) `array()` function in a side comment: _To create an array, we can use a library function array() and pass the item values to it, so that array(1, 2, 3) creates an array [1, 2, 3]._

Comment: Although I like Kotlin but I have say "Kotlin documentation" is not good enough (I learned more from other sites than kotlinlang.org).

Comment: Also sometime you just want an intRange you could do: `val numbers = 1..5` which gives an int range from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 499, accepted):

```
val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

See [Kotlin - Basic Types](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html) for details.

You can also provide an initializer function as a second parameter:

```kotlin
val numbers = IntArray(5) { 10 * (it + 1) }
// [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Comment: Is it preferable to use `intArrayOf` over `arrayOf`? Thus does `IntArray` have advantages over `Array<Int>`?

Comment: @LarsBlumberg IntArray is equals to int[], Array<Int> is the same as Integer[]

Comment: Initializing a list is very similar: `listOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)`

Comment: When I am using intArrayOf() function, I face `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinPackage`. I am using `jdk1.8.0_241` and Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 120):

Worth mentioning that when using kotlin builtines (e.g. `intArrayOf()`, `longArrayOf()`, `arrayOf()`, etc) you are not able to initialize the array with default values (or all values to desired value) for a given size, instead you need to do initialize via calling according to class constructor.

```
// Array of integers of a size of N
val arr = IntArray(N)

// Array of integers of a size of N initialized with a default value of 2
val arr = IntArray(N) { i -> 2 }
```

Comment: That second default value init using the lambda was super helpful!  Thanks

Comment: The second form of initialization can be written as: `IntArray(N) {i -> 2}` and even (when initializing with a constant) `IntArray(N) {2}`

Comment: Instead of i we can use "_" var arr = IntArray(N){ _ -> false}

Comment: That one with the lambda was exactly what I needed to init an array with dynamic size and non-optional default value. Thanks!

Answer (score 83):

In Kotlin There are Several Ways.

```
var arr = IntArray(size) // construct with only size
```

Then simply initial value from users or from another collection or wherever you want.

```
var arr = IntArray(size){0}  // construct with size and fill array with 0
var arr = IntArray(size){it} // construct with size and fill with its index
```

We also can create array with built in function like-

```
var arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // create an array with 5 values
```

Another way

```
var arr = Array(size){0} // it will create an integer array
var arr = Array<String>(size){"$it"} // this will create array with "0", "1", "2" and so on.
```

You also can use `doubleArrayOf()` or `DoubleArray()` or any primitive type instead of Int.

Comment: `var arr = IntArray(size, { it * 1 } )` is the same as `var arr = IntArray(size){it}`

Answer (score 50):

Here's an example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3);
    for (item in arr) {
        println(item);
    }
}
```

You can also use a [playground](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt) to test language features.

Comment: One comment, to print value of an array, we can use array.joinToString(" ") instead looping.

Comment: Works but looks more Java written in Kotlin than idiomatic Kotlin :)

Answer (score 39):

In Kotlin we can create array using `arrayOf()`, `intArrayOf()`, `charArrayOf()`, `booleanArrayOf()`, `longArrayOf()` functions.

For example:

```
var Arr1 = arrayOf(1,10,4,6,15)  
var Arr2 = arrayOf<Int>(1,10,4,6,15)  
var Arr3 = arrayOf<String>("Surat","Mumbai","Rajkot")  
var Arr4 = arrayOf(1,10,4, "Ajay","Prakesh")  
var Arr5: IntArray = intArrayOf(5,10,15,20)
```

Comment: Please reformat this Answer so it is clear what is code and what is comment.

Comment: FYI for anybody reading this answer ... using arrayOf for primitives is less optimized than say intArrayOf. Also, arrayOf creates objects while inArrayOf retains the primitives

Answer (score 14):

Old question, but if you'd like to use a range:

```
var numbers: IntArray = IntRange(10, 50).step(10).toList().toIntArray()
```

Yields nearly the same result as:

```
var numbers = Array(5, { i -> i*10 + 10 })
```

result: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50

I think the first option is a little more readable. Both work.

Answer (score 11):

Kotlin has specialized classes to represent arrays of primitive types without boxing overhead. For instance – `IntArray`, `ShortArray`, `ByteArray`, etc. I need to say that these classes have no inheritance relation to the parent `Array` class, but they have the same set of methods and properties. Each of them also has a corresponding factory function. So, to initialise an array with values in Kotlin you just need to type this:

```
val myArr: IntArray = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

...or this way:

```
val myArr = Array<Int>(5, { i -> ((i + 1) * 10) })

myArr.forEach { println(it) }                            // 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
```

Now you can use it:

```
myArr[0] = (myArr[1] + myArr[2]) - myArr[3]
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use this methods

```
var numbers=Array<Int>(size,init)
var numbers=IntArray(size,init)
var numbers= intArrayOf(1,2,3)
```

example

```
var numbers = Array<Int>(5, { i -> 0 })
```

init represents the default value ( initialize )

Comment: It helps if you give examples for `init` in `Array<Int>()` and `IntArray()`, your answer isn't much helpful as of now.

Comment: The answer has been modified

Comment: Array<Int> gives you an array of boxed Integers, whereas IntArray gets you an actual int array.

Answer (score 3):

I think one thing that is worth mentioning and isn't intuitive enough from the documentation is that, when you use a factory function to create an array and you specify it's size, the array is initialized with values that are equal to their index values. For example, in an array such as this:
`val array = Array(5, { i -> i })`, the initial values assigned are `[0,1,2,3,4]` and not say, `[0,0,0,0,0]`. That is why from the documentation, `val asc = Array(5, { i -> (i * i).toString() })` produces an answer of `["0", "1", "4", "9", "16"]`

Answer (score 3):

You can create an Int Array like this:

```
val numbers = IntArray(5, { 10 * (it + 1) })
```

5 is the Int Array size. the lambda function is the element init function. 'it' range in [0,4], plus 1 make range in [1,5]

origin function is:

```
 /**
 * An array of ints. When targeting the JVM, instances of this class are 
 * represented as `int[]`.
 * @constructor Creates a new array of the specified [size], with all elements 
 *  initialized to zero.
 */
 public class IntArray(size: Int) {
       /**
        * Creates a new array of the specified [size], where each element is 
        * calculated by calling the specified
        * [init] function. The [init] function returns an array element given 
        * its index.
        */
      public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> Int)
  ...
 }
```

IntArray class defined in the Arrays.kt

Answer (score 3):

My answer complements @maroun these are some ways to initialize an array:

Use an array

```
val numbers = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Use a strict array

```
val numbers = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Mix types of matrices

```
val numbers = arrayOf(1,2,3.0,4f)
```

Nesting arrays

```
val numbersInitials = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val numbers = arrayOf(numbersInitials, arrayOf(6,7,8,9,10))
```

Ability to start with dynamic code

```
val numbers = Array(5){ it*2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var a = Array<Int>(5){0}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the existing standard library [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48035025/8073652) as shown here:

```
val numbers = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

It might make sense to use a special constructor though:

```
val numbers2 = IntArray(5) { (it + 1) * 10 }
```

You pass a size and a lambda that describes how to init the values. Here's the documentation:

```
/**
 * Creates a new array of the specified [size], where each element is calculated by calling the specified
 * [init] function. The [init] function returns an array element given its index.
 */
public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>I'm wondering why nobody just gave the most simple of answers:</s>

```
val array: Array<Int> = [1, 2, 3]
```

As per one of the comments to my original answer, I realized this only works when used in annotations arguments (which was really unexpected for me).

Looks like Kotlin doesn't allow to create array literals outside annotations.

For instance, look at this code using @Option from args4j library:

```
    @Option(
        name = "-h",
        aliases = ["--help", "-?"],
        usage = "Show this help"
    )
    var help: Boolean = false
```

The option argument "aliases" is of type `Array<String>`

Comment: I have got the following error with this code : Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]

Comment: I haven't seen this before. Is this syntax new to Kotlin?

Comment: @LarsBlumberg, probably, I just started to use Kotlin recently with IntelliJ 2019.1 and I initialized a string array just like I showed and it worked

Comment: @RémiP, Good point, I used it on annotations arguments. But that would mean that array literals works in some contexts and in some other don't?

Comment: @hdkrus Why don't you update your answer to show how array initialization works with annotations? This can be of value for many readers of this questions.

Comment: I'm wondering why this syntax is working for annotations but not in regular code? Maybe the same technique can be applied?

Comment: How is this specific annotation declared?

Comment: I cannot imagine why only on annotations, but looks like it's supposed to work for any annotation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters

Answer (score 2):

While initializing string check below

```
val strings = arrayOf("January", "February", "March")
```

We can easily initialize a primitive int array using its dedicated arrayOf method:

```
val integers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has already have good answers.
Here is a consolidated one to create int array.

1. Creating array with specific values.

   ```
   var arr = intArrayOf(12,2,21,43,23)
   var arr = arrayOf<Int>(12,2,21,43,23)
   ```

> [12, 2, 21, 43, 23]

2. Filling with specific element. Here its 1.

   ```
   var arr  = IntArray(5).apply{fill(1)}
   val arr  = IntArray(5){1}
   ```

> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

3. Filling array of size 5 with random numbers less than 20

   ```
   val arr  = IntArray(5) { Random.nextInt(20) }
   ```

> [0, 2, 18, 3, 12]

4. Filling array elements , based on position.
   Here array is filled with multiples of 5.

   ```
   val arr  = IntArray(5) { i -> (i + 1) * 5 }
   ```

> [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below:

```
val numbers = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

or

```
val numbers = arrayOf<Int>(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

also

```
val numbers = arrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin There are Several Way to initialized an Array:

**arrayof():**

```
var myarray = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

**arrayOf():**

```
var myarray = arrayOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5)
```

**Using the Array constructor:**

```
val num = Array(3, {i-> i*1})
```

**built-in factory methods:**

```
val num1 = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
//For Byte Datatype
val num2 = byteArrayOf()
//For Character Datatype
val num3 = charArrayOf()
//For short Datatype
val num4 = shortArrayOf()
//For long
val num5 = longArrayOf()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I need to initialise my drawer items. I fill data by below code.

```
    val iconsArr : IntArray = resources.getIntArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_icon)
    val names : Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_name)


    // Use lambda function to add data in my custom model class i.e. DrawerItem
    val drawerItems = Array<DrawerItem>(iconsArr.size, init = 
                         { index -> DrawerItem(iconsArr[index], names[index])})
    Log.d(LOGGER_TAG, "Number of items in drawer is: "+ drawerItems.size)
```

Custom Model class-

```
class DrawerItem(var icon: Int, var name: String) {

}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in a sensible way.

Comment: Please check comment in which I used lambda function to add items.

Comment: This still seems like a convoluted way to solve this problem, at least compared to the other answers. Also I looked at my previous message, and it seems harsh in retrospect - I'm sorry.

Comment: That is fine, no issue. I just tried to answer in a way which resolved my issue, I didn't compared with other answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

intialize array in this way : `val paramValueList : Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls<String>(5)`

Answer (score 1):

Declare int array at global

```
var numbers= intArrayOf()
```

next onCreate method initialize your array with value

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //create your int array here
    numbers= intArrayOf(10,20,30,40,50)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way:

**For Integer:**

var number  = arrayOf< Int>
(10 , 20 , 30 , 40 ,50)

**Hold All data types**

var number = arrayOf(10 , "string value" , 10.5)

Answer (score 0):

In Java an array can be initialized such as:

```
int numbers[] = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
```

But In Kotlin an array initialized many way such as:

Any generic type of array you can use **arrayOf()**  function :

```
val arr = arrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

val genericArray = arrayOf(10, "Stack", 30.00, 40, "Fifty")
```

Using utility functions of Kotlin an array can be initialized

```
val intArray = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can initialize the int array in koltin.

```
 val values: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

for 2-dimentions array:

```
val rows = 3
val cols = 3
val value = 0
val array = Array(rows) { Array<Int>(cols) { value } }
```

you could change element type to any type you want (String, Class, ...) and value to the corresponding default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an ArrayList to populate and then return an array from that.
Below method will add 10,000 elements of Item type in the list and then return a Array of Item.

```
private fun populateArray(): Array<Item> {
    val mutableArray = ArrayList<Item>()
    for (i in 1..10_000) {
        mutableArray.add(Item("Item Number $i" ))
    }
    return mutableArray.toTypedArray()
}
```

The Item data class will look like this:

```
data class Item(val textView: String)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example

```
val id_1: Int = 1
val ids: IntArray = intArrayOf(id_1)
```