# how to initialization array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

In Java an array can be initialized such as:

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

How does Kotlin's array initialization look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366229/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-kotlin

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35253626/2196460

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize using

```
val MONTHS = arrayof("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
val MONTHS = arrayOf("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array, we can use a library function `arrayOf()` and pass the item values to it, so that `arrayOf("1", "2", "3")`.

You can use:

```
val MONTHS = arrayOf("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```

Also you can use specialized classes to represent arrays of primitive types as `ByteArray`, `ShortArray`, `IntArray`.

In this case you can use:

```
val x: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
```

More detailed [info here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html).